# Unable to use apply-templates with node-set - XSLT

Tags: xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0, node-set

I am trying to get distinct values of shelf and add them to xml tree using node-set. I am trying to print the values of node-set using apply-templates. But I am doing something wrong. Kindly correct me. Thanks

```
  <xsl:template name="form_list">
        <xsl:for-each select="//library/section/@shelf[generate-id()= generate-id(key('distinct_shelfs',.)[1])]">
    
        <xsl:variable name="shelfs">
            <ml>
            <m><xsl:value-of select="."/></m>
            </ml>
        </xsl:variable> 
          
        </xsl:for-each>
    
    <xsl:variable name="Shelf_Set"><xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($shelfs)/ml"/></xsl:variable>
    
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:call-template name="PrintShelfs"/> 
    
    <xsl:template name="PrintShelfs">
    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$Shelf_Set" mode="m1"/>
    
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ml" mode="m1" >
    
    <a><xsl:value-of select='.'/></a>
    
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please psot a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.-- P.S. You seem to have a `xsl:call-template` instruction outside of any template - that would generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

The `xsl:value-of` instruction flattens a node-set to a single text node. I suspect you want simply

```
<xsl:variable name="Shelf_Set" select="exsl:node-set($shelfs)/ml"/>
```

Comment: I made the suggested change, however i'm facing the error : Exception in thread "main" 
org.apache.xpath.XPathException: Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList!  for this line of code --->  <xsl:apply-templates select="$Shelf_Set" mode="m1"/>

Comment: Can't see any reason for that but if you're using Xalan, then you're using Java, which means there's no reason to still be using XSLT 1.0 which was superseded about 15 years ago.

Comment: I am limited to use XSLT 1.0 , is there anything I can do?

Comment: As I say, I moved forward from XSLT 1.0 about 15 years ago, so I've forgotten all the crazy workarounds you had to use in that world.

Comment: I changed the version of stylesheet to 2.0, perhaps there is some mistake in the code written. I am a newbie to this language and unable to proceed furthur. It would be nice if I can get some help

Comment: Setting the version attribute says that you would like to use XSLT 2.0 features; it doesn't magically turn your XSLT 1.0 processor into an XSLT 2.0 processor.